# Adding "cc" to mail task in ANT

Tags: email, ant

This is regarding   regarding "Sending e-mail" task in ANT. I want to add a "cc" in the Send-mail target.

When I addded the "cc" e-mail, it is giving me an exception "mail doesn't support the nested "cclist" element". Can you please let me know as to what the issue is.

Below is the ANT target for sending e-mail.

```
<target description="Generates and send junit test reports" name="send-report">
  <mail mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" mailport="25" password="testing" ssl="true" subject="Junit Test Reports for Timescity" user="testing@gmail.com">
     <from address="teseting@gmail.com"></from>
     <replyto address="testing@gmail.com"></replyto>
     <to address="abc@gmail.com"></to>
     <cclist address="xyz@gmail.com"></cclist>
     <message>testing for sending email</message>
     <attachments>
       <fileset dir="E:\mail\cucumber\target\cucumber-junit-report">
          <include name="**/*.zip"></include>
      </fileset>
     </attachments>
  </mail>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mail task takes either a single `cclist="..."` *attribute* or one or more `<cc>` *elements*, so you need

```
<cc address="xyz@gmail.com"></cc>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `<cc>`, not `<cclist>`:

```
<cc address="xyz@gmail.com"/>
```

Source: [Ant's `<mail>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html)

Answer (score 0):

**< cc/>** is equivalent to **< cclist/>** but you use it when this parameter specified as nested element.

Source: Ant's Mail task